# How to upgrade ruby on cygwin from source?

Tags: ruby, cygwin

I installed ruby 1.9.1 from source on cygwin about 9 months ago. I did a default install i.e make, make test, make install which installed it in /usr/local. I am now trying to install 1.92. After building and installing it using the same steps, I found the gems I had installed stopped working. I though this might happen so I made a back up first and was unable to recover. Is there a way to install it without disturbing the previously installed libriaries or should I just bite the bullet and re-install them? I am also begining to think that installing it in the default location might not have been a good idea as it would be hard to tell what files are ruby and what are not if other things were also installed in this location also. I am guessing there is no such thing as make uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not be the answer you're looking for, but I highly recommend you take a look at [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/), which is a Ruby version manager that works on Windows.

It's similar to [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com), which is the de-facto way to install and manage Rubies on Mac OS and *nix.

Comment: According to the website, pik only works on Ruby 1.8.7    have you ever used in on Windows with 1.9.x ?